# How to add hawt.io to ActiveMQ 5.11.1

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I tried to enable hawtio interface in Apache ActiveMQ like described in [How to configure the ActiveMQ 5.10.0 HawtIO interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674726/how-to-configure-the-activemq-5-10-0-hawtio-interface/27842112) which is obviously based on http://sensatic.net/activemq/activemq-and-hawtio.html.

I am able to see the logon screen of hawt.io when I access http://localhost:12345/hawtio but get a "`Failed to login. Forbidden`" when I use the login credentials that perfectly work with the standard webconsole that comes with ActiveMQ.

The necessary changes have been put into the env file:

```
if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/login.config -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=admins -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal "
```

I don't see any reason for this. Two remarks (I don't know if this might be relevant): as you can see I changed the default port from 8161 to a different value. And I configured Jetty to only listen on localhost and use a ssh tunnel.

Is the "Forbidden" message a hint for me that I need to have a look at `./webapps/hawtio/WEB-INF/classes/jolokia-access.xml` ?

Comment: Did you configure the security role in your startup scripts? 
-Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=admins   -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal

Comment: @TimBish   Yes, like I was told in the linked documents. I put the changed lines of the env file into my question, please have a look there

Comment: I have the very same issue. When I disable Hawtio authentication by adding `-Dhawtio.authenticationEnabled=false` to the parameter list I am able to access hawtio and all wanted data at least.